# How to "cast" an instance to a subclass?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I have an instance of class message I'll call "msg". I have defined a class "my-message" and would like instance "msg" to now be of that class.

It sounds to me like it should be relatively straightforward, but I don't know how to do it. change-class gives me an error I don't understand.

```
(defclass my-message (message)
  ((account-name :accessor account-name :initform nil :initarg :account-name)))

(change-class msg 'my-message :account-name account-name)

ERROR :
While computing the class precedence list of the class named MW::MY-MESSAGE.
The class named MW::MESSAGE is a forward referenced class.
The class named MW::MESSAGE is a direct superclass of the class named MW::MY-MESSAGE.
```

Comment: You say you have an instance of class `msg`. In your code you use a class `message`. Where is this class `message` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> The class named MW::MESSAGE is a forward referenced class.
> ```

A forward referenced class is a class that you reference but have not yet defined. If you look at the name of the class, it is `MW::MESSAGE`. I suppose you want to subclass another class named `MESSAGE` in another package; there might be something wrong with the symbols you import.

> ```
> The class named MW::MESSAGE is a direct superclass of the class named MW::MY-MESSAGE.
> ```

Since the `MW::MESSAGE` class is not yet defined, you cannot make an instance of it. This is also why you cannot make an instance of any of its subclasses, such as `MW::MY-MESSAGE`.

Comment: It was indeed a symbol problem. I was missing what a "forward referenced class" was. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
CL-USER>  (defclass message () ())
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::MESSAGE>

CL-USER> (defparameter *msg* (make-instance 'message))
*MSG*

CL-USER> (describe *msg*)
#<MESSAGE {1002FE43F3}>
  [standard-object]
No slots.


CL-USER> (defclass my-message (message)
           ((account-name :accessor account-name
                          :initform nil
                          :initarg :account-name)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-MESSAGE>

CL-USER> (change-class *msg* 'my-message  :account-name "foo")
#<MY-MESSAGE {1002FE43F3}>

CL-USER> (describe *msg*)
#<MY-MESSAGE {1002FE43F3}>
  [standard-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  ACCOUNT-NAME  = "foo"
```

Note that this is not a *cast*, since the object itself will be changed. It is now an instance of a different class. *casting* would usually mean that just the interpretation of the unchanged thing changes in some context. But here the instance is really changed and the old interpretation no longer applies.